# Subtracting current from previous row by date and ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'd like to extend this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244681/retrieve-previous-row-to-subtract-from-current-row-by-date#) by including an ID as a grouping column. I tried including a 'group by' clause without success.

```
+----------+--------------+----------
|NAV_Date  |NetAssetValue |  ID      |
+----------+--------------+---------+
|12/31/2012|        $4,000|     A     |
+----------+--------------+---------+
|03/31/2013|        $5,000|     A     |
+----------+--------------+---------+
|12/31/2012|        $4,000|     B     |
+----------+--------------+---------+
|03/31/2013|        $5,000|     B     |
+----------+--------------+---------+
```

```
select NAV_date, NAV_value, (NAV_value / prev_value) - 1
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 NAV_value
              from YOURTABLENAMEGOESHERE as t2
              where t2.NAV_date < t.NAV_date
              group by Nav_ID, Nav_value
              order by t2.NAV_date desc
             ) as prev_value
      from YOURTABLENAMEGOESHERE as t
     ) as t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    NAV_date, 
    NAV_value, 
    (NAV_value / 
        (select top 1 NAV_value
        from YOURTABLENAMEGOESHERE as t2
        where t2.NAV_date < t.NAV_date
        order by t2.NAV_date desc) - 1
from 
    YOURTABLENAMEGOESHERE as t
```